# Find and open limited number of files across several external hard drives

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, terminal, media

I have 11 external hard drives containing thousands of videos. In my lobby I need to select a random 100 or so to open and play so that a new set is playing every day. I have used programs like [Find Any File](https://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/) but do not have enough options. I am wondering if Terminal on my Mac could do this.

Comment: You could throw the whole lot at VLC with 'shuffle' on. No-one will ever realise the choice per day is not random; only the overall 'shuffle' is random… playing each video once before recycling the same list. I have to admit I've never done this with 11 drives' worth of tracks to see what the overhead is, but I often do it with several hundred videos.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried that but VLC can't open the amount of files I have across all drives.

Comment: Divide into manageable playlists, maybe one per drive - pick a playlist at random each day, or just by disk name… I'm sure this is one you can break down into manageable chunks - though again, I have no experience with massive databases like this.

Comment: Appreciate the input again, but have exhausted all of these 'organic' approaches. Really need a program or command line to get this running properly.